# Export TS to support ES6, CommonJS, and HTML <script> tag

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs

I'm coding up a TS library that exports an object like this:

```
export const MyLibName: SDKExport = { ... }
```

This library will be distributed on npm and I want others to be able to import it regardless of their setup, i.e. it should be able to be used in the following ways:

```
// ES6
import { MyLibName } from './myLib';

// CommonJS
const { MyLibName } = require('./myLib');

// Browser
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/myLib/dist/dist.min.js"></script>
<script console.log(MyLibName) </script>
```

The browser part is proving to be the most tricky since it requires "polluting" the global namespace with the `MyLibName` object. I can do that, but it's unclear to me how to do it in a way that doesn't pollute the global namespace when importing the library explicitly using CommonJS/ES6.

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode", "test"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that the script you're importing in the browser must be a different thing than your CommonJS/ES6 import if you want one to pollute the global namespace but not the other. Just create a file like this one and use your bundler on it to create a "browser build" of your library:

```
import { MyLibName } from './myLib';
window.MyLibName = MyLibName;
```

(You seem to have a bundler/minifier in your project already so I won't go into detail on how to set up those.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the [approach suggested by Vojtěch Strnad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69370137/1452257) with [browserify](https://browserify.org), but encountered issues that were hard to debug due to all the extra code that browserify adds to the exported files. I'm accepting that answer as it's the correct one for complex codebases.

For my own project, which only includes a single file, I found that it worked well to export the TS code using the `"module": "ES6"` TS compiler options and run `sed -i 's/\export //g' dist/index.js` to remove the `export` keyword. That way, the exported file simply has `const MyLibName = { ... }` and thereby adds the object to the global namespace.